# Photocell and Relay switch not working properly

Tags: switches, relay, photoresistor, photosensor

I am trying to build a simple circuit to switch on and off my garden lights according to the brightness level. More to the point, I'd like the lights to turn on when it's dark and off in the morning.

The solution I've come up with is the following, but somehow it is not working properly.

[image]

I use a 12V battery, in conjunction with a 12V relay switch, a 12V 4.5W LED lamp (in the picture it is shown as a single LED) and a photocell.

According to the specs, the resistance of the photocell should be 10K Ohms during the day and around 600K Ohms at night. Below are the datasheets

Relay: https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf

Photocell (Photoresistor) https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/photocells.pdf

Is the circuit ok? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: If the photocell resistance only drops to 10K in light, it can't possibly control a relay that requires 30 mA.

Comment: What Peter said. A quick scan of your docs show that the photoresistor is limiting current to the relay's coil - this means that the battery will never supply enough current for the switch to close. Do you have an arduino of pic micro lying around? I think that would be the most straightforward way to proceed. Sample the voltage across a divider circuit, and choose some hysteresis bounds to control a BJT.

Comment: What a silly mistake, I am an amateur sorry. Yes I have an Arduino however I was hoping to avoid using it and build a stand alone unit to replicate for the other garden lights (they're quite far apart, using wires would be unpractical and wireless communication seems too hard for a beginner as myself).

Comment: @RYS do you have any hints or suggestion on how I can fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I an embedded solution might be easiest for you, but you can try something like this:
[image]

Where the transistor is something like a 2N3904, and the diode could be an IN4007. The pot on R2 should be maybe 10k-20k range, the resistor at the base of the transistor should be around 1k, and depending on the resistance of your particular relay, you may also need a small series resistance between emitter and ground to make sure you don't give the transistor too much current.